# Apply CSS to all divs in a container before current div only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Lets say we have this layout:

```
<div id="container">

    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="current"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>

</div>
```

With some CSS:

```
#container div {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

How can I make all divs before and including the div (within `#container`) with class `current` have the same background colour e.g. `background: tomato;`? And update if the div that the `class="current"` is on changes?

So in the example above the first 3 divs within the container would have a background colour of tomato.

Comment: With out knowing if the previous divs you are referring to are siblings or parents this is almost impossible to answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors).

```css
#container div {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  
  background-color:tomato;
}

#container .current ~ div {
  background-color:transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div class="current">3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>

</div>
```

Comment: That's a nice one!  CSS only, did not even know that was possible.

Comment: @CupawnTae The answer was edited but originally there wasn't a declaration of exact divs targeted in the question. Just that previous divs would need to be selected.

Comment: @Marcelo If there were multiple containers, lets say another container before this one with the same layout ... how would you make all divs in that one also have the background colour (because they are before the current class)?

Answer (score 2):

here is a different way of working it out

http://jsfiddle.net/27LjLqm2/

```
<div id="container">

<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div class="current">3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>

</div>


#container div {
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
background:tomato;
}

#container div:nth-last-child(-n+2){
background:transparent;
}
```

we are targeting the last DIV of the list

" -n " being beneath the 5th  div so the +2  will make us go to the top twice.

using "+1" would make "div 5" background transparent.

+2 would go all the way from "div 5 to div 4" and make their background transparent.

you can play a bit with it by using +3 then +4 to see what gets changed

Comment: needs to change based on which div has the `"current"` class

Comment: Where is the "-n" use documented?  With which browsers is it compatible?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard a minute

Comment: I just tested it in Firefox, and it works there.  I'm trying to find "n" in the specs.  If you can point me to some documentation for it, that would be fantastic.

Comment: I haven't clicked on that link... is that source legal?  What about in the actual CSS spec?  It must be in the spec somewhere, but I must be looking in the wrong section.

Comment: the link was pointing to an ebook i have myself. i man not sure if legal so i took it down.
the best way to read about it is to start from w3c.com type selectors, all  specs are discussed, nth-of-type, nth-child, nth-last-child... with simple examples.
here is the link :http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Answer (score 1):

while you tagged Jquery .. in jQuery you need to use **.[prevAll](http://api.jquery.com/prevall/)('div')**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.current').prevAll('div').css('background','tomato');
});
```

and you ask for first 3 divs

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.current').css('background','tomato').prevAll('div').css('background','tomato');
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/unkp777b/)

Comment: He asked for a css solution this is Javascript with the jQuery library

Comment: Where does he say he needs a CSS solution?  The question is tagged with Javascript and jQuery as well.   If I understand the OP correctly, there is not even any CSS only solution to this problem.

Comment: My mistake, as he never made mention of any other language and his question actually missing a lot of info I did not think JS was a possible solution. But even with JS the question is pretty vague here as to what he's targeting outside the stated elements.

Comment: Thanks that's perfect! I'm still quite new to all these languages, so wasn't sure which would provide the solution - sorry for any confusion!

Comment: @wadclapp are you using JS and jQuery already? Because if not then that's a lot additional resources that are just masking a bad coding technique rather than proper DOM structure and styling usage(CSS).

Comment: @wadclapp never mind .. but I think css solution from Marcelo is a best one :)

Comment: Well, he did say "And update if the div that the `class="current"` is on changes", which this doesn't do (PS downvote wasn't me :-)

Comment: @CupawnTae I understand that but if he is using jQuery just to mask bad coding and all he needs is styling change based on an event then jQuery is overkill and raw JS and proper CSS would be much cleaner code. Not to mention relying on jQuery is very bad habit if you're not already sound in JS, I think Mohamed has a good answer but the OP is very vague and there's no telling what platform, libraries, stack and DOM he has loaded in this question.

Comment: @BrianEllis I'm not sure if you're misinterpreting my point - all I was saying was that this answer actually doesn't fulfil the requirements in the question, so any discussion about choice of tech aside, it's actually not fully correct.

Comment: @CupawnTae Sorry, I fully agree and flagged the question as being too vague. But he registered, got his answer and flew the coop. I'm worried more now about someone stumbling on the page and getting bad info or confused to no end about CSS in general, let alone the other languages.

Comment: Thanks for providing the jQuery solution, it was tagged with it after all so its good to be complete so anyone checking this out can see all the possible solutions

Answer (score 0):

```
#container div:not(.current ~ div) {
    background: red;
}
```

[Good browser support, too](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3)